# Trying to play sound on pressing Info Button in MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkitannotation

I'm writing an IOS app that basically shows custom points of interest in my area. For that I'm using MapKit and MKAnnotations. Now I had someone offer me to record the text I want to display so that people with visual impairments can use the app as well. My plan is to have the info button in the callout play those recorded sounds.
Here's the code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "recording.mp3", ofType: nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer.play()

            print("click")
            print(path)
            print(url)

        } catch {
            // errors
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the sound doesn't play, but I don't get any errors. I'm printing out "click", "path", and "url" and everything seems in order, the button gets clicked and the paths look correct to me.
I have a hunch that I'm trying to override a system sound and that may be the problem but I'm a bit stuck and don't know what to try next.

Comment: Because your player is a local variable. It goes out of existence before it can start playing.

Comment: Thank you so much, that would have taken me ages to figure out.